# MySQL with Sequelize: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am following a tutorial and below is the code:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var sequelize = new Sequelize('basic-mysql-database.mysql', 'root', 'password', {
    'dialect': 'mysql',
    'host': "localhost",
    "port": "3306"
});

var Todo = sequelize.define('todo', {
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    completed: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN

    }
})

sequelize.sync().then(function(){
    console.log('Everything is synced')

    Todo.create({
        description: 'Walking my dog',
        completed: false
    }).then(function (todo){
        console.log('Finished!')
        console.log(todo)
    })
});
```

I have installed MySQL.  When I go into `Settings` > `MySQL` and it says `MySQL Server instance is running`

When I run `node testDB.js` I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'basic-mysql-database.mysql'
    at Handshake._callback (/Users/Kausi/Documents/Development/todo-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:63:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Users/Kausi/Documents/Development/todo-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:85:24)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/Kausi/Documents/Development/todo-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:105:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/Kausi/Documents/Development/todo-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/Users/Kausi/Documents/Development/todo-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:74:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/Kausi/Documents/Development/todo-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Kausi/Documents/Development/todo-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:536:20)
```

I have never created any schema/table.  I do have MySQL Workbench that I can create the schema and 'Todo' table with; however, I was under the impression that `Sequelize` does this on the fly?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think sequelize can make a database for you. It will only make a tables for you. Create that database first then just let the sequlizer create your table (just create your database)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a tiny little line in the setup that says:

> The credentials for the respective database

Sync will create the tables for you, but it's not going to create the database.

Comment: but what if we want to do this job with our app... like don't have to create our database manually just our will do this for us.. is their any way??

Answer (score 0):

In mac I navigated to /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

And found that my username was "root" and password was also "root"

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root';
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78066825/12228079