# I'm getting unknown database error while connecting to mysql through node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

PS G:\boot> node hello.js
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^

Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'boot'
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
at Handshake.ErrorPacket (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket. (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket. (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (G:\boot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
at Object. (G:\boot\hello.js:22:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
errno: 1049,
sqlMessage: "Unknown database 'boot'",
sqlState: '42000',
fatal: true
}

**code is**

```
const express = require('express')
var mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
// app.use(express.static('css'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('signup.html', { root: __dirname })
});

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'boot'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('Connected.........')
})

connection.end();

app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Data saved',
    message: 'Data saved successfully'
  })
})

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
)
```

Comment: The `sqlMessage` is exactly what it says. There is no `boot` database.

Comment: @danblack There is ```boot``` database in phpmyadmin. Under this created a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'boot` error is returned from your MySQL server. This means your MySQL server that you host in your local does not have a database with name `boot`, or the `root` user does not have access to the database.

Recommend you to double check that you have initiated the database with the `boot` name before rerunning your app

Comment: It's showing same error for other previously created databases. Also the username  ```root``` is correct

Comment: can you try to remove the `database` parameter and see whats the new errors?

Comment: can you also try to add the port in the options, you probably not using the default port for your db connection

Comment: Now I know the problem. I'm using wampp , so in wampp i have 2 server i.e., ```MySql``` and ```MariaDB```. The connection is done to mariaDB instead of Mysql. If you see the code, it is var connection = mysql.createConnection not MariaDB. Still it connects to MariaDB. Help me with this

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me

In mac I navigated to /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

And found that my username was "root" and password was also "root"

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root';
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78066825/12228079