# node.js sequelize - mysql Unkown database problem

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, database-connection

I'm trying to make a website by using node.js, mysql and sequelize with my friends, so I downloaded database files my friend made.
But I cannot create and recognize database table.
How can I fix this problem..?
I already tried "  sequelize db:create " on the server terminal.
The error codes I got are

```
{ SequelizeConnectionError: Unknown database 'database_development'
   at ...
 name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
 parent:
  { Error: Unknown database 'database_development'
      at ....
    code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
    errno: 1049,
    sqlState: '42000',
    sqlMessage: 'Unknown database \'database_development\'' },
 original:
  { Error: Unknown database 'database_development'
      at .....
    code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
    errno: 1049,
    sqlState: '42000',
    sqlMessage: 'Unknown database \'database_development\'' } }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584169/mysql-with-sequelize-er-bad-db-error-unknown-database
I solved this problem, unknown database Problem was occured because sequelize only creates table, not database.

Answer (score 0):

use following command to create `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS <db_name>;`